# Customizing User Messaging Platform (UMP) Dialog in Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, customization, ads, ump

I'm currently implementing the User Messaging Platform (UMP) library in my Android app to manage consent for ads. However, I would like to customize the appearance of the UMP consent dialog to match the onboarding experience of my app.

Is there a way to replace the standard UMP dialog with a custom view that I design and control programmatically? I want to display the consent options within my app's onboarding flow instead of a separate dialog.

I've already integrated the UMP library, and the consent dialog is displayed when necessary. Now, I just need to make it more visually consistent with the rest of my app.

**Additional Information**:

- Android app using UMP library
- Looking for a way to replace the UMP dialog with a custom view
- Seeking guidance on how to integrate this custom view into the onboarding flow
- Any code snippets or examples would be greatly appreciated!

I've explored the documentation and attempted various approaches to customize the UMP dialog, but it seems that with the current library, there is no straightforward way to achieve this. I expected to find a solution to integrate the consent options seamlessly into my app's onboarding process.

Comment: You can first create a popup which will ask the consent for ads from the user if they click allow or something then you can load UMP Dialog I dont think we can change the appearance of UMP itself